# Remove multiplication symbol (×) from URL

Tags: javascript, url, symbols, multiplication

Below is a URL in which multiplication symbol `×` is coming. It is not 'x'. I checked for its ascii value but was not able to find it. I only got how to create it (alt+158).
URL:
 `http://localhost:6000/SearchService/SearchService.svc/GetSearchResults?srchKeyword=test×projectId=2&user=3`
I am creating this url in javascript. I tried replacing `%C3%97`with empty string but it didn't worked. Kindly tell me how to remove it as i am getting incorrect result.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace this character using `String.prototype.replace`:

```js
var url = "http://localhost:6000/SearchService/SearchService.svc/GetSearchResults?srchKeyword=test×projectId=2&user=3";

document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + url + "</p>";

url = url.replace('×', '');

document.body.innerHTML += "<p>" + url + "</p>";
```

At the same time, it is a good idea to understand the reason of appearance of this character instead of handling the consequences.

Comment: This will only replace the first occurrence. To replace all, use `url = url.replace(/×/g, '')`

Comment: I am using token input in search textbox and in that there is an image to delete the keyword. Its my guess that I might be getting that as multiplication symbol but I am not sure about it. :(